# Why DatabaseGeneratedAttribute dosen't work with Guid?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
 [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]  
public virtual System.Guid ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I've already used newid() with the database field and also tried DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity, but I still get `"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"` in the database.

Comment: explained here: http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4/

Comment: Use DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity

Comment: @paul thank you, but  I'm use code first  without  edmx File.

Comment: @StuartDunkeld I tried identity option,but it dosen't work.

Comment: I tried with EF 5.0 and it worked. Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: I couldn't get any of those to work, so I switched to a nullable type, i.e. `Guid?`.